# =ISNUMBER(SEARCH()) formula not working properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Basically, im trying to search if values from column b is contained in cells on column a

[image: https://imgur.com/UevybZP]

I am currently using the formula

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,$A:$A))
```

and using it inside a conditional formatting to highlight the cells in column A that contains strings from column B. But it is not highlighting the correct cells

any advice?

Comment: Could this be related to the fact that your number columns are formatted like text?

Comment: hi, yes it is currently formatted as text. should it be on general to work?

Comment: hi, i changed them to general then number format but still not working. it should be true for 2234 as A2 contains 2234 but still false in the output of formula

Comment: @dotNET I might consider find()...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(….` formula is returning an array of values `{FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;...}` one return for each item in `within_text`.  You need to know if **any** of those items match.

So, with your formula, consider the **array** formula modification

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,$A:$A)))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

*If you don't like to use the `CSE` entry method, you could use this formula which will return zero for no matches, or be non-zero for any matches:*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,$A:$A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel's `SEARCH` function is used to find the position of one **string** within another **string**. Generally you use it like this:

```
=SEARCH("String A", "A Longer String Containing String A")
```

This will return the character index where first string starts within the second string, which in this case would be `28`.

What you really need is a `VLOOKUP`. Since you're doing a textual search (substring), you need your range to be of text type instead of number.

You should do the following:

- Add an extra column to the right of Column A and use `TEXT` function to convert entries to textual form:

  ```
  =TEXT(A1, "@")
  ```
- Now you can use `VLOOKUP` to perform a substring-match in this textual range. `VLOOKUP` supports wildcards when you do not ask it to perform an exact match (4th argument should be `FALSE`). Here is your formula then:

  ```
  =VLOOKUP("*" & C1 & "*",$B:$B,1,FALSE)
  ```

Note that I have passed column B (textual column) as the lookup range, whereas `C1` is the cell containing the text that you want to search.

This method also has the additional advantage that it returns the actual matched entry from the range so you don't have to find it manually.

Once you have your results, you can apply conditional formatting to it.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight column A (or the relevant range in column A starting cell `A1`) with the first cell (which is `A1` in this case) as the active cell, use the following formula as the conditional formatting rule:

```
=(SEARCH($B1,$A1)*(LEN($B1)>0))>0
```

> The logic is to first search the given sub-string from the main string, then multiple the result by `LEN($B1)>0` to exclude the result of `1` returned for blank cells in column B.

[image: Demo]

*Note: **Conditional Formatting** works in `array` fashion so even though the formula only looks at values in the first row of the range, as long as you use the relative (or in some cases absolute) cell references correctly and highlight the result range correctly before setting up the rule, the rule will be applied across in the same way as for the first row of the array as demonstrated in this example.*